# Arduino MKR 1010 WiFi as BLE central/client

Tags: bluetooth, mkr1010, ble

I'm trying to use my new Arduino MKR 1010 WiFi as a Bluetooth Low Energy **central**/**client**, however I could only find information on how to use it as a *peripheral/server* (for example with the [ArduinoBLE library](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/ArduinoBLE), which only supports peripheral mode).

Is this possible? Maybe with a different library or firmware for the integrated NINA-W102 chip?

Comment: were you able to use it as central device?

Comment: @EinSoldiatGott Unfortunately not. I ended up using the ESP32 which worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case this thread turns up in a search, the [ArduinoBLE](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/ArduinoBLE) library now includes central and peripheral support.